# Run-time Error 3075 in MS Access while appending email distribution to table via SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following function defined in MS Access VBA:

```
Function SendToEMail(iTo As String, iFrom As String, icc As String, ibcc As String, iSubject As String, iBody As String, iSystem As String, iAttachments As String)
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblEmail ([To], [From], [CC], [BCC], [Subject], [Body], [Create_Time], [System], [Attachments]) IN '\\ahmtroy03\Email.accdb' VALUES ('" & iTo & "', '" & iFrom & "', '" & icc & "', '" & ibcc & "', '" & iSubject & "', '" & iBody & "', #" & Now() & "#, '" & iSystem & "', '" & iAttachments & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Function
```

This function inserts records into a table. Each record is an email. When appending to this table, I get error 3075 and it references the [To] field. I've changed some info for privacy. All other distributions come through okay but THIS one doesn't make it.

firstname.last-name@something-corporation.com, firstname.last-name@something-corporation.com, firstname.lastname@something-corporation.com, firstname.lastname@something-corporation.com, firstname.lastname@something-corporation.com, firstname.lastname@something-corporation.com

Comment: VBA supports breaking a long line of code into multiple lines using a line continuation character sequence at the end of the line.  That would be a space followed by an underscore.  It would make your code much easier to read.

Comment: The Attachments field gets data? I would be surprised. If Attachments is an attachment type field, should not be able to enter objects into attachment field like that. http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/working-with-attachment-fields.html

Comment: @June7 it's custom. It takes a test varibale that is either a file path or folder path. If it's a file, it gets attached. If it's a folder, each file in the folder get attached.

Comment: This is just an insert into a table. What happens after is working fine. Actually getting the data into the table is where this error is happening.